# Symbol manipulation in lisp macro

Tags: macros, common-lisp, symbols

I'm writing a toy interpreter for a Lisp language, in which I have the following CL code:

```lisp
(defun mal-list (&rest args)
  (make-mal :type 'list
            :value args))
(register-fun '|list| #'mal-list)

(defun mal-list? (arg)
  (eq (mal-type arg) 'list))
(register-fun '|list?| #'mal-list?)
```

However, I'd rather simply write something like this:

```lisp
(defmal list (&rest args)
   (make-mal :type 'list
             :value args))

(defmal list? (arg)
   (eq (mal-type arg) 'list))
```

I tried to write a macro to do this, but I had problems with the symbols with the bars (I'm pretty confused as to what this is!). This is what I tried:

```lisp
(defmacro defmal (name args &body body )
  (let ((funsym (intern (format nil "~{~a~}" `(mal- ,name)))))
    `(register-fun `|,name| (defun ,funsym ,args ,@body))))
```

which didn't work out, because `` `|,name| `` literaly meant `|,name|`, and not `|list|`

I'm guessing this is an XY problem, but I'm not sure how to approach this otherwise.

Comment: Symbols have names.  By default, when the reader encounters, e.g., `foo`, it gets the string `"foo"`, upcases it to get `"FOO"`, and interns that to obtain the symbol `FOO`.  But symbols don't have to have upcased names.  If you intern `"foo"` (as opposed to `"FOO"`) you get a symbol that will probably be printed `\f\o\o` or `|foo|`.

Comment: `(format nil "~{~a~}"` is unpredictable, because `*print-case*` could be set to a variety of things.  `(format nil "~a" 'foo)` could return "foo", "FOO", or "Foo".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|...|` syntax is just one of the ways that the Lisp printer can print symbols that have characters in their name that need to be escaped (and that the reader can *read* symbols with those kinds of characters in their names):

```
(print (intern "foo"))
;=> |foo|
```

There are other ways, too, including escaping individual characters:

```
(print '|FOO|)
;=> FOO

(print '\f\o\o)
;=> |foo|
```

What you're trying to do is simply create a symbol whose name includes lower case letters.  That's easy enough, as shown above.  Part of your issue, though, is that you're getting as input a symbol whose name is full of capital letters, so you'll need to downcase first:

```
CL-USER> (symbol-name 'FOO)
;=> "FOO"

CL-USER> (intern (symbol-name 'FOO))
;=> FOO

CL-USER> (string-downcase (symbol-name 'FOO))
;=> "foo"

CL-USER> (intern (string-downcase (symbol-name 'FOO)))
;=> |foo|
```

In fact, because **string-downcase** takes *string designators*, not just strings, you can pass the symbol in directly:

```
CL-USER> (intern (string-downcase 'BaR))
;=> |bar|
```

So, after all that string processing, we can move to the macro.

---

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```
(defmacro defmal (name lambda-list &body body)
  (let ((mal-name (intern (concatenate 'string "MAL-" (symbol-name name))))
        (mal-norm (intern (string-downcase name))))
    `(progn
       (defun ,mal-name ,lambda-list
          ,@body)
       (register-function ',mal-norm #',mal-name))))
```

```
CL-USER> (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(defmal list? (arg)
                                  (eq (mal-type arg) 'list))))

(PROGN
 (DEFUN MAL-LIST? (ARG) (EQ (MAL-TYPE ARG) 'LIST))
 (REGISTER-FUNCTION '|list?| #'MAL-LIST?))
```

---

It's generally a good idea to avoid using **format** in generating symbol names, because the specific output can change, depending on other variables.  E.g.:

```
(loop for case in '(:upcase :downcase :capitalize)
   collect (let ((*print-case* case))
             (format nil "~a" 'foo)))
;=> ("FOO" "foo" "Foo")
```

Instead, you can use **concatenate** with a string (or the symbol name of a symbol).  Because the *reader* can also have different settings for case sensitivity, sometimes I'll even do (but not everyone likes this):

```
(concatenate 'string (symbol-name '#:mal-) (symbol-name name))
```

This way, if the reader does anything unusual (e.g., preserves case, so that the symbol name of `mal-` is `"mal-`), you can preserve it in your own generated symbol, too.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [Joshua's detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32597599/124319), consider using a function from the [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html) library:

- `format-symbol` is like [`format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_format.htm), but inside [`with-standard-io-syntax`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_std_.htm). Here, `t` stands for the current package and *name* is downcased:

  ```
  (format-symbol t "mal-~(~A~)" name)
  => |mal-list|
  ```
- `symbolicate` concatenates and interns in current package:

  ```
  (symbolicate '#:mal- name)
  ```

  You can end-up with either `|MAL-LIST|` or `|mal-list|` if your current readtable preserves case or not. For completeness, note that `readtable-case` can be set to the [following values](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_c.htm#case_sensitivity_mode): `:upcase`, `:downcase`, `:preserve` or `:invert` (this one I find quite interesting).

Comment: :invert is very interesting, and makes writing FFI/interoperability/CamelCased code much easier.  All lower-case keeps the "usual" behavior, e.g., `(defun foo () ...) => (DEFUN FOO () ...)`, but `(defun listProcesses () ...) => (DEFUN |listProcesses| () ...)`.